# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, как

Родственники могут как эффективно помочь, так и очень существенно навредить игроку.

Answer (score 2):

**КАК... ТАК И...**
Состав­ной союз, соеди­ня­ющий одно­род­ные чле­ны пред­ло­же­ния; **запятая ставится только** перед второй частью союза, **перед словом "так"**.
[**Запятые в предложении с союзом КАК... ТАК И...**](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/zapjatye-kak-tak-i.html)

В предложении нет срав­ни­тель­но­го обо­ро­та. Между одно­род­ны­ми сказуемыми (***могут помочь*** и ***навредить***) мож­но исполь­зо­вать сочи­ни­тель­ный соеди­ни­тель­ный союз «и».
Тогда пред­ло­же­ние при­мет сле­ду­ю­щий  вид:
*Родственники могут эффективно помочь и очень существенно навредить игроку.*

Предложения с правильной пунктуацией:

*Родственники могут **как** эффективно помочь, **так и** очень существенно навредить игроку.*

*Все окна **как** в барском доме, **так и** в людских отворены настежь* (Салтыков-Щедрин).

*Вдали вид­не­ют­ся **как** обла­ка, **так и** сине­ва­тая дым­ка над гор­ны­ми вер­ши­на­ми.*

*Знойным лет­ним днем с реч­ки доно­сят­ся **как** гомон и визг счаст­ли­вой ребят­ни, **так и** шум мотор­ных лодок.*

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, запятая перед *"как"* не нужна, а нужна только перед *"так"*. Смотрите [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_352).